# Basic Temperature converter in HTML using Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm having trouble getting this basic HTML temperature converter to work. Basically, the user enters in the box "tempinput" a temperature and selects either if the input is in C/F/K.

Once that's done, the user clicks on convert and the function convert() should run, displaying in the box "result" the temperature in the 2 other choices (So if C is selected, F and K would be displayed in the box).

Problem is, although it's a simple program and everything seems straightforward, it doesn't seem to be working. I've been trying to figure out what's not working to no avail.

Here's the code:

```js
function convert() {
    var temp = document.getElementById("initialtemp");
    var valueSelected = temp.options[options.selectedIndex].value;

    if (valueSelected == "c") {
      var convertedF = cToF();
      var convertedK = cToK();

      return document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = convertedF + "F" + " = " + convertedK + "K";
    } else if (valueSelected == "f") {
      var convertedC = fToC();
      var convertedK = fToK();

      return document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = convertedC + "C" + " = " + convertedK + "K";
    } else if (valueSelected == "k") {
      var convertedF = kToF();
      var convertedC = kToC();

      return document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = convertedF + "F" + " = " + convertedC + "C";
    }
  }
  // celcius to rest

function cToF() {
  var c = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
  return (c * 9 / 5) + 32;
}

function cToK() {
    var c = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
    return c + 273.15;
  }
  // fahrenheit to rest

function fToC() {
  var f = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
  return (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
}

function fToK() {
    var f = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
    return (f - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15;
  }
  // kelvin to rest

function kToC() {
  var k = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
  return k - 273.15;
}

function kToF() {
  var k = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
  return (k - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32;
}
```

```html
<h1>Temperature Converter</h1>
<div>
  <h2>Celcius: "C" Fahrenheit: "F" Kelvin: "K"</h2>
  Temperature:
  <input type="text" id="tempinput">
  <select size="3" id="initialtemp">
    <option value="c" selected>C
      <option value="f">F
        <option value="k">K
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>Result:
  <input type="text" id="result">
  <button type="button" onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you run the code snippet, an error will show up in the console when you click Convert indicating the `options` is not defined. Look at the second line of `convert`; you use `temp.options` and then just `options`.

Comment: You don't need to use `selectedIndex` to get the value of a `<select>`. Just use `temp.value`.

Comment: You're missing `</option>` in your HTML.

Comment: Make sure you use parseFloat to parse the input. Right now you are getting strings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTML

Your options need a closing  tag.

```
<option value="c" selected>C</option>
<option value="f">F</option>
<option value="k">K</option>
```

### JS

In order to get the value of the select element you have to use the .value property.

```
var valueSelected = document.getElementById("initialtemp").value;
```

Lastly in order to update the output element with your generated string you have to use the .value property and not the .innerHTML one.

```
document.getElementById("result").value = convertedF + "F" + " = " + convertedK + "K";
```

Answer (score 0):

your code after some fixes

```js
function convert() {
    var temp = document.getElementById("initialtemp");
    var valueSelected = temp.value;

    if (valueSelected == "c") {
      var convertedF = cToF();
      var convertedK = cToK();

      return document.getElementById("result").value = convertedF + "F" + " = " + convertedK + "K";
    } else if (valueSelected == "f") {
      var convertedC = fToC();
      var convertedK = fToK();

      return document.getElementById("result").value = convertedC + "C" + " = " + convertedK + "K";
    } else if (valueSelected == "k") {
      var convertedF = kToF();
      var convertedC = kToC();

      return document.getElementById("result").value = convertedF + "F" + " = " + convertedC + "C";
    }
  }
  // celcius to rest

function cToF() {
  var c = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
  return (c * 9 / 5) + 32;
}

function cToK() {
    var c = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
    return c + 273.15;
  }
  // fahrenheit to rest

function fToC() {
  var f = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
  return (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
}

function fToK() {
    var f = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
    return (f - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15;
  }
  // kelvin to rest

function kToC() {
  var k = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
  return k - 273.15;
}

function kToF() {
  var k = document.getElementById("tempinput").value;
  return (k - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32;
}
```

```html
<h1>Temperature Converter</h1>
<div>
  <h2>Celcius: "C" Fahrenheit: "F" Kelvin: "K"</h2>
  Temperature:
  <input type="text" id="tempinput" />
  <select size="3" id="initialtemp">
    <option value="c" selected>C</option>
    <option value="f">F</option>
    <option value="k">K</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>Result:
  <input type="text" id="result"/>
  <button type="button" onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
</div>
```